# Postgres minor version upgrade

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

What is the recommended method to perform a minor version upgrade of postgres on linux (Centos)? I am looking at upgrading from 9.5.4 to 9.5.5.

Comment: what operating system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do a `dist-upgrade` or the like on Linux, or install the newer versions on Windows/OSX. Minor versions ensure total compatibility with the data directory (heap, and index).

Stands to reason though, you'll have to *stop* the database during the upgrade.

From the [official docs on versioning](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

> Minor releases are numbered by increasing the last part of the version number. Beginning with version 10, this is the second part of the version number, e.g. 10.0 to 10.1; for older versions this is the third part of the version number, e.g. 9.5.3 to 9.5.4. The PostgreSQL team only adds bug fixes to minor releases. All users should upgrade to the most recent minor release as soon as possible. **While upgrades always have some risk, PostgreSQL minor releases fix only frequently-encountered, security, and data corruption bugs to reduce the risk of upgrading. The community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading.**

So essentially, PostgreSQL is so conservative that minor-version number upgrades are only issued when there is more risk to not-upgrading than upgrading. I've been working with PostgreSQL for about 15 years. I don't do any additional backups nor take any special precautions when doing minor upgrades. Not saying you can't -- even the docs say they come with "some risk."

Comment: Just to be safe can I do a side-side upgrade? Install 9.5.5 and then point the db to it?

Comment: you can, but that is in my opinion a total waste of time. =)

Comment: @sharadov It's not a bad idea: then you can prewarm your new version before directing traffic there.  If you're worried about something breaking, you can switch your users in batches (probably not necessary given the conservative release policy, but couldn't hurt!).

Comment: @sharadov since you had concerns, if you haven't already, I would recommend implementing a comprehensive backup strategy: occasional full backups and frequent incremental/differential backups, spread across at least two locations.  While a minor upgrade is not dangerous in the grand scheme of things, they are on a long list of "things that can go wrong".  IMHO these rules apply from huge corporations to tiny startups, and bring a lot of comfort.

Answer (score 4):

In short, a minor upgrade of a Postgres installation (also called cluster) is rather simple:

- stop the cluster
- replace the Postgres binaries with the new version 
  (the details may differ here, depending on OS and flavour)
- restart the cluster

---

For a production system and a DBA that tries to be more careful, there are two more things:

- a **backup** could be done before the upgrade.
- **reading** the **release notes** is a must before executing the upgrade.

  There are sometimes cases, that even a minor upgrade requires extra steps. Sometimes it's rebuilding some indexes, sometimes more weird stuff, etc. More often than not, you don't have to do anything extra, but reading these notes is essential as when some extra work is needed, it is to prevent some bug from not being fixed or to invert some corruption, etc.

  If you want to upgrade (example) from 9.5.4 to 9.5.9, you need to **read all the intermediate release notes**, too (9.5.5, 9.5.6, 9.5.7, 9.5.8, 9.5.9). For the specific 9.5.5 notes, see below.

So the steps would be:

- **reading** the **release notes** and altering the procedure accordingly
- stop all connections and prevent new ones
- take a backup (either of the whole cluster with with `pg_basebackup` or of each database with `pg_dump`)
- stop the cluster
- replace the Postgres binaries with the new version
- restart the cluster

---

If there is replication involved, you'll have to consider that, too:

For a production system and a DBA that tries to be more careful, a backup could be done before the upgrade:

- stop all connections and prevent new ones
- wait for all replicas to catch up
  and take backup
- stop all clusters (master and replicas)
- replace the Postgres binaries with the new version (in each cluster)
- restart all clusters

A variation in this case is the backing up can be skipped, if we keep one or more replicas stopped and with the old binaries. If for any reason, we need to go back to the old minor version, we can promote that replica to master.

---

For the specific 9.5.5 release for example, the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/release-9-5-5.html) say:

> E.5. **Release 9.5.5**
>
> Release date: 2016-10-27
>
> This release contains a variety of fixes from 9.5.4. For information about new features in the 9.5 major release, see Section E.10.
>
> E.5.1. **Migration to Version 9.5.5**
>
> **A dump/restore is not required for those running 9.5.X.**
>
> **However, if your installation has been affected by the bug described in the first changelog entry below**, then after updating **you may need to take action** to repair corrupted free space maps.
>
> Also, **if you are upgrading from a version earlier than 9.5.2**, see Section E.8.

So, we need to read this first changelog, too:

> E.5.2. **Changes**
>
> Fix WAL-logging of truncation of relation free space maps and visibility maps (Pavan Deolasee, Heikki Linnakangas)
>
> It was possible for these files to not be correctly restored during crash recovery, or to be written incorrectly on a standby server. Bogus entries in a free space map could lead to attempts to access pages that have been truncated away from the relation itself, **typically producing errors like `"could not read block XXX: read only 0 of 8192 bytes"`**. Checksum failures in the visibility map are also possible, if checksumming is enabled.
>
> **Procedures for determining whether there is a problem** and repairing it if so are discussed at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Free_Space_Map_Problems.

So, dump/restore is not required for moving from 9.5.4 to 9.5.5 and you only need to check for this specific issue. Check your error logs and you are good to go ;)

Comment: Since this is a prod server, I was planning to install 9.5.5 on the same server and then just point the database to it, so that I can revert back should we run into issues.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean with "point the database to it".

Comment: We use an environment file, so we just need to point the env variable to the new ver.

Comment: @sharadov: if you can convince `yum update postgresql-server` to not override the existing binaries, then you could do a "side-by-side" installation

Comment: Has there *ever* been a case where a dump restore was required in the change logs for a minor upgrade version? I think they just put that there for boilerplate. If a dump restore was required, it'd be a major version upgrade.. right?

Comment: That's not a minor release though. That's a major release.

Comment: @EvanCarrollQWERHJKL correct, I can't find a case when it was required for a minor version. Edited out.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum update  postgresql-version
```